# what's the meaning of the "value" attribute in @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm wondering what's the purpose of the "value" attribute in the org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping. for example :

**@RequestMapping(value="/person/count")**

Comment: Does your IDE automatically load source code and javadocs? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats the url that needs to be called to invoke the method - its the actual request mapping.

Comment: Could you give me a HelloWorld example please ? :)

Comment: no, use a bit of effort yourself : there a tons of tutroials all over the web.

Comment: @ayoubuntu just follow the video in MVC showcase http://www.springsource.org/node/2717

Comment: i've read many topics on this subject but still i don't understand the syntax of the path that should i put in the "value" attribute, and what does mean the first "/", this is the root of what ?!